# .to_numpy() doesn't bring string values into the array

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, dataframe, numpy

For each Lab Location, I'm trying to calculate a count of work items and average the time intervals recorded on each work item. When I apply groupby to this dataframe....

```
dfGroupBy = df.groupby(df['Lab Location']).agg({'ADO ID' : 'count', 'RequestedInterval' : 'mean','TargetedInterval' : 'mean', 'ActualInterval' : 'mean', 'Duration End' : 'mean', 'Duration SignOff' : 'mean'})
#print(dfGroupBy)
```

.... I get this output:

```
Lab Location       ADO ID   RequestedInterval   TargetedInterval    ActualInterval  
                                                                   
ABC                 1               59.000000           45.000000               NaN   
XYZ                 137             27.195489           27.476923           22.491071   
CBA                 10              17.100000           65.222222           28.000000   
ZYX                 11              65.000000           101.545455              NaN
```

When I attempt to convert the dataframe to a numpy array....

```
dfGroupByArr = dfGroupBy.to_numpy()
print(dfGroupByArr)
```

the output shows that the string column containing the lab location is not included in the Numpy array.

```
[[  1.          59.          45.                  nan          nan
           nan]
 [137.          27.19548872  27.47692308  22.49107143  22.49107143
   29.80733945]
 [ 10.          17.1         65.22222222  28.          28.
   23.        ]
 [ 11.          65.         101.54545455          nan          nan
           nan]]
```

I need these categorical descriptions of the lab location to create bar graphs and calculate different means.

Any suggestions how I can include the strings in the Numpy array?

Or any suggestions to calculate the counts and the mean using just Pandas?

Comment: Because Lab Location is an index, `reset_index()` and then convert to array

Answer (score 0):

Anky is correct. Adding .reset_index() to the groupby makes all the difference

```
dfGroupBy = df.groupby(df['Lab Location']).agg({'ADO ID' : 'count', 'RequestedInterval' : 'mean','TargetedInterval' : 'mean', 'ActualInterval' : 'mean', 'Duration End' : 'mean', 'Duration SignOff' : 'mean'}).reset_index()

dfGroupByArr = dfGroupBy.to_numpy()
```

The output now includes the lab locations in the array